# how to use android plugin sdk in unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

For example, i have [LiveKit SDK](https://github.com/livekit/client-sdk-android) for Android and i need to integrate this plugin into my Unity project for android devices.

I have searched for many tutorials, but none of them had good explanation how to implement this whole SDK to my project and properly use it

In addition, i just took livekit.aar file from .gradle folder and put it in unity project
Then, I coded it like that

```
private void Start() {
    AndroidJavaClass liveKit = new AndroidJavaClass("io.livekit.android.LiveKit");
    devInf.text = "Found LiveKit Class";
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject applicationContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

    AndroidJavaObject room = liveKit.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("create", applicationContext);

    token = PlayerPrefs.GetString("stream-token", "");
    Debug.LogWarning(token);

    StartCoroutine(ConnectCoroutine(room, url, token));
    //Invoke("CreateRoomWithDelay", 3f);
}

IEnumerator ConnectCoroutine(AndroidJavaObject room, string url, string token) {
    devInf.text = "Starting Connection";
    yield return room.Call<IEnumerator>("connect", url, token);

    AndroidJavaObject localParticipant = room.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("localParticipant");

    if (localParticipant != null) {
        AndroidJavaObject audioTrack = localParticipant.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("createAudioTrack");
        AndroidJavaObject videoTrack = localParticipant.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("createVideoTrack");

        localParticipant.Call("publishAudioTrack", audioTrack);
        localParticipant.Call("publishVideoTrack", videoTrack);

        localParticipant.Call("setCameraEnabled", true); 
        localParticipant.Call("setMicrophoneEnabled", true); 
    }
}
```

this is how i realized livekit in android studio

```
fun startStream() {
    val cfgData = getCfgData.getData()
    viewModelScope.launch {

        if (token != null) {
            room.connect(STREAM_URL, token)
            val localParticipant = room.localParticipant
            val videoTrack = localParticipant.createVideoTrack(
                "video",
                LocalVideoTrackOptions(position = CameraPosition.BACK)
            )
            localParticipant.publishVideoTrack(videoTrack)

            val audioTrack = localParticipant.createAudioTrack(
                "audio",
                LocalAudioTrackOptions()
            )
            localParticipant.publishAudioTrack(audioTrack)

            localParticipant.setCameraEnabled(true)
            localParticipant.setMicrophoneEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveKit has unity plugin so you shouldn't need to install Android SDK separately.

But if you want to know how to add android libraries to the Unity, here are the steps:

##### Adding Android library from Maven repository:

1. Download and install External Dependency Manager for Unity. https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver (there is external-dependency-manager-latest.unitypackage)
2. In your Assets directory, create "Editor" directory
3. Inside "Editor" create XML file and name it as you like, e.g. MyDependencies.xml
4. In XML add:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
   <dependencies>
     <androidPackages>
       <repositories>
         <repository>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</repository>
         <repository>https://jitpack.io</repository>
       </repositories>
       <androidPackage spec="io.livekit:livekit-android:2.0.1"/>
     </androidPackages>
   </dependencies>
   ```
5. I would recommend enabling `Custom Main Gradle Template` and `Custom Gradle Properties Templete` in `Edit > Project Setting > Player > Android > Publishing Settings`. When templates are enabled, External Dependency Manager will use Gradle to resolve dependencies, which works a lot better than Dependency manager's own implementation.
6. Then proceed to `Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Resolve`
7. If you have enabled minification in `Publishing Settings` and are working with added Android library from C#, you may face class not found/defined errors. In that case you will need to enable `Custom Proguard File` and add:

   ```
   -keep class io.livekit.** { public *; }
   ```

##### Adding Android library as .aar archive:

1. Copy .aar file to the `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory
2. If needed, add custom Proguard rules to avoid code obfuscation.

   **Note** that many Android libraries have transitive dependencies, which means that also dependencies' aar files needs to be added.

Comment: 1st advice didn't work out, it fails on building, requests more dependencies (i tried to add it but it seems it doesn't work). maybe we could do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u7FV-e6nUc)?

Comment: I know that there is LiveKit SDK for unity, but it is for WebGL. So I need to find a way to use in Unity Android

Comment: I have updated the answer. I didn't check their docs, and my answer initially lacked the https://jitpack.io repository.

Comment: now it builds, now I have to fathom out how to solve this problem in Android logcat
`Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='create' signature='(Landroid.app.Application;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;  
Error Unity java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='create' signature='(Landroid.app.Application;)Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;`
my code is above, I wrote it looking at [LiveKit Docs](https://docs.livekit.io/client-sdk-android/index.html). It would be great if you have any suggestion

Comment: LiveKit Docs are written in Kotlin, but C# is working directly with Java bytecode. So, according to source, `create` method is a member of `LiveKit` companion object. During compilation, Kotlin adds $default suffix to such members. So correct method name in Java will be `create$default`. Also, after compilation for such methods, Kotlin always add parent class as first input parameter.

Comment: Additionally, Kotlin makes some optimizations, so at the end your method has the following signature: `(Lio.livekit.android.LiveKit;Landroid.app.Context;Lio.livekit.android.RoomOptions;Lio.livekit.android.LiveKitOverrides;ILjava.lang.Object;)Lio.livekit.android.room.Room;`

Comment: The simplest way to check how the desired method looks like is to unzip aar and then use javap command. For example `javap classes.jar io.livekit.android.LiveKit`
Or if it is already too time-consuming, you can create a custom android library that will work directly with Kotlin as it is intended in LiveKit docs and then add this library to the Unity and then from C# call methods from your custom library

Comment: I made my own android library, but I still have some issues. Here is my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154237/whats-wrong-in-my-usage-of-android-plugin-in-unity)