# What's wrong in my usage of android plugin in unity?

Tags: android, kotlin, unity-game-engine

I made a plugin to work with [LiveKit SDK](https://github.com/livekit/client-sdk-android) in unity.
When I patch and run my app on phone it displays error in Android Logcat

```
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field INSTANCE of type Lio/livekit/android/LiveKit; in class Lio/livekit/android/LiveKit; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.livekit.android.LiveKit' appears in /data/app/~~BC1yiJxYnjbz3X2zedFAZQ==/com.DefaultCompany.Myproject1-SgP7HCJfzbWMD53FwL8ZMQ==/base.apk)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field INSTANCE of type Lio/livekit/android/LiveKit; in class Lio/livekit/android/LiveKit; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.livekit.android.LiveKit' appears in /data/app/~~BC1yiJxYnjbz3X2zedFAZQ==/com.DefaultCompany.Myproject1-SgP7HCJfzbWMD53FwL8ZMQ==/base.apk)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at com.northside_shawty.unitylivekit.LiveKitManager.ConnectToRoom(LiveKitManager.kt:15)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$500(Unknown Source:0)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:126)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
2024.03.13 16:44:14.799 20358 20436 Error Unity     at andro
```

I don't see any INSTANCE in LiveKit class in their docs

It just has one class that i needed

```
class LiveKitManager {
    fun ConnectToRoom(context: Context, url: String, token: String) {
        val room = LiveKit.create(context)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            room.connect(url, token)
            val localParticipant = room.localParticipant
            val videoTrack = localParticipant.createVideoTrack(
                "video",
                LocalVideoTrackOptions(position = CameraPosition.BACK)
            )
            localParticipant.publishVideoTrack(videoTrack)

            val audioTrack = localParticipant.createAudioTrack(
                "audio",
                LocalAudioTrackOptions()
            )
            localParticipant.publishAudioTrack(audioTrack)

            localParticipant.setCameraEnabled(true)
            localParticipant.setMicrophoneEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I've built my Android Library and put .aar file from Android project in my Unity project.

This is how I interact with my plugin

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Stream : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url;
    public string token;

    void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaObject liveKitManager = new AndroidJavaObject("com.northside_shawty.unitylivekit.LiveKitManager");
        AndroidJavaObject context = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")
                                                     .GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity")
                                                     .Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

        liveKitManager.Call("ConnectToRoom", context, url, token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had 2.0.1 version of LiveKit SDK. I've just changed it to 1.5.3 and it worked out. Now it only needs proper work with permissions

Answer (score 0):

INSTANCE field is generated by Kotlin for every object. When you from custom library execute `LiveKit.create(context)` Kotlin will compile it to the bytecode that is equivalent to the following Java code:

`LiveKit.create$default(LiveKit.INSTANCE, context, ...`

The only way it could be not found is if "INSTANCE" name was changed by Proguard.

Maybe try to add exception for it. Enable `Project Setting > Player > Publishing Settings > Custom Proguard File`

And in `Assets/Plugins/Android/proguard-user.txt` add the following:

```
-keep class io.livekit.android.LiveKit {
    *** INSTANCE;
}
```